# How to solve the PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im creating a query in my repository that updates some user's fields, however I keep getting this error: `PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:` 
I tried the proposed solutions in stackoverflow which say I need to change the `"cascade = CascadeType.ALL"` to `"cascade = CascadeType.MERGE"` but still doesn't work for me.

**user entity:**

```
........
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer                             userId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String                              username;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {
        CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH
    }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address", updatable = true)
    private Address             address;
```

**UserRepository:**

```
  @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update user u set u.address = :address where u.userId = :userId")
    public int updateUserEtablissementAndLabels(
        @Param("userId") Integer userId,
        @Param("address ") Address address 
    );
```

Comment: Please show us what you are doing with entities in the transaction that throws the exception. Also show the complete stack trace. 
This has almost certainly nothing to do with the repository method you show except for it triggering a flush.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the problem was the cascades, so i resolved the problem by removin the cascadetype = persist and cascadeType = refresh